# Vite and dynamic CSS imports - Deprecated Warning

Tags: css, typescript, import, dynamic, vite

I like to have for my application a dynamic css import, because I like to have the theme for my application at runtime applied so it can be changed by the user.

I used therefore the import statements for CSS like this:

```
import(`./resources/themes/${theme}/css/style.css`);
```

This works. However I see in the console a warning and seems that it in future release will be deprecated in vite?

```
Default import of CSS without `?inline` is deprecated. Add the `{ query: '?inline' }` glob option to fix this.
```

I then tried several options like to declare a module

```
declare module '*.css?inline' {
  const content: string;
  export default content;
}
```

and then import with "?inline" but the warning still gets reported.

```
let {default: content} = await import(`./resources/themes/${theme}/css/style.css?inline`);
  const styleElement = document.createElement('style');
  // Set the CSS content
  styleElement.textContent = content;
  // Append the <style> element to the document head
  document.head.appendChild(styleElement);
```

Any suggestions how this can be correctly handled with vite?

I am using currently vite 4.4.11 with typescript 5.1.6